# Where is Visual Studio's regasm.exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio

What it the path to the regasm that is used by Visual Studio, when 'Register for interop' is selected?  The Project is using .Net framework 4.5.1 but I'm not sure it that implies that  it's regasm.exe is used.

Comment: You could always use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see which executable it launched.

Comment: smart answer - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ *VERSION* \RegAsm.exe

Comment: where version is that of the project's framework (e.g. v4.0.30319, for 4.5.1) - is this a definitive association?, I guess it probable. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to know it's location. Instead, you should use [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to launch it, as the prompt sets your PATH environment variable appropriately to locate all tools like regasm.exe.

Comment: another smart answer